# A professor wants to schedule a total of three hours of office hours for the next five days...

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways is that possible if the length of each office hour must be an integer (in hours)?

This question is from the book 'A Walk Through Combinatorics' and it has no solution.

My attempt so far is recognizing that this can only be done in hours of 1, 2 or 3. By that I mean the professor can have three slots of 1 hour, a slot of 2 hours and one slot of 1 hour, or one slot of 3 hours.
In 5 days, there are 5*24 = 120 hours, so this leads me to believe that the answer should be
120C1 + (120C2 * 120C1) + 120C3

I'm not sure if this makes much sense though as I'm a beginner when it comes to combinatorial questions. I'd appreciate any help I can get if I'm wrong.

Comment: Can the prof choose *any* of the 24 hours in a day for OH? If so, there are 120 possible one-hour slots over 5 days, three of which must be chosen for OH, giving $120\choose 3$ scheduling options.

Comment: I'm assuming so because that's how the question is phrased. Do we only need to look at the one hour slots when computing such a question? Don't we need to note down the different combinations that'll arise if he keeps 2 or 3 hour OH?

Comment: my solution includes those cases, since choosing e.g. three back-to-back one hour slots is equivalent to choosing one three-hour slot.

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. It says the professor wants to schedule $a+b+c+d+e=3$ hours total, where one possible $(a, b, c, d, e) =(1, 0,0,2,0) $.

Comment: @MyMolecules Ah, that makes more sense for this kind of exercise. Thanks.